# Besicovitch via Baire: questions

Tags: general-topology

I have some problems understanding the proof in the LEMMA 2.4 in TW Körner's paper ***Besicovitch via Baire*** (2003) (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1090.5109&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

[image]

In the proof, he constructed a translated set from the set $P$ and claims that $P'\in \mathcal{P}$. However, it is not true if there is a line segment $l$ through $(x,v)$ which joins $(x_0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, where $x<0$. Right translation makes $l$ not in $[-1,1] \times [0,1]$ anymore.

Could anyone who had read the paper offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it is not true if there is a line segment $l$ through $(x,v)$ which joins $(x_0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, where $x<0$.

This situation you mention never occurs. From Definition 2.1, property (ii), the only line segments $l(x,\theta)$ you need to consider in the definition of $P'$ are those with $|\theta| \geq \arctan 2$. (In other words, the slope of $l(x,\theta)$ is $\geq 2$ or $\leq -2$). If one of these line segments has $(1,1)$ as an endpoint, then it lies completely in the right-half-plane $(0, \infty) \times \mathbb R$, so it gets translated to the left, not to the right.